# How to guarantee differentiability?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

According to my calculus book the following holds. Given that $h\to0$:

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f'(x)+f'(x))=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h})=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$

But then the book claims that the existence of the limit in $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ does **not** guarantee that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. This can be shown by taking $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$. Then the limit gives $0$, while $f'(0)$ should be *not defined* at $x=0$.

**Question:** Although I can follow the example with $f(x)=|x|$ above, I do not understand why the existence of the limit in $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ would **not** guarantee that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. It seems to say that $f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$, then why doesn't it also guarantee that $f$ is differentiable at $x$? Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't forget to put in the $\lim_{h\to 0}$ in the equations above... szia!

Comment: Actually, my comment above is more than syntactic - it's an explanation. Going (i.e., reading) from right to left, the limit distributes over the $+$ sign *on condition*  the limits involved exist.

Comment: @peterag but why is that so?

Comment: Example: in $ \lim_{x\to 0} 0= \lim_{x\to 0} \left( 1/x - 1/x\right) = \lim_{x\to 0} 1/x - \lim_{x\to 0} 1/x = ? -? $, the second equality is not valid. Do you agree?

Comment: Sorry for all the editing of the previous - it looks ok now

Comment: Namely, though certainly $0=\lim_{x\to 0} 0$, and $0 =1/x -1/x$ , for $x\not=0$, I cannot use this to conclude the existence of the $\lim_{x\to 0} 1/x$.

Comment: Also - you probably want a $-$ sign in front of your second denominator $h$...

Comment: @peterag the - sign is would not be correct in front of the second denominator h

Comment: Add the two terms that you currently have - you won't get what you have on the far right.

Comment: @peterag Ah, yeah, sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the same situation that you can't conclude any thing about $\lim u$ and $\lim v$ even when $\lim u+v$ is exist and finite. For example, take $\lim( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x})=0$ when $ x\rightarrow 0$ but you can't separate into 2 limit. The differential is the existence and finiteness of the $\lim \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $\lim u$ above

Answer (score 2):

Let us first see again the defintion of differentiability. $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if  $$  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \quad  \text{ and }  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$
exist and equal. Then these limits, both, are  equal to  $f'(x)$.

Now to see that the existance of  the limit  $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}  $$
doesnot impliy that $f$ is differentiable at $x$,  consider the question :

**Does the existance of this last limit guarantee the existance  and the equality of the limits:** $$  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \quad  \text{ and }  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

The answer of this question is **no**. Check the counter example you give in the question: take  $f(x)=|x|$ and check differentiablity at  $x=0$. Indeed, we have 
$$  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{|h|-0}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}  \frac{h}{h}=1 \quad  \text{ and }  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{|h|-0}{h}=   \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{-h}{h}=-1$$ however 
 $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|h|-|-h|}{2h}=0  $$

Comment: It's not a matter of left and right hand limits. Rather it is the issue raised by  @Peterag in the comments

Comment: yes I notcied that, however I am answering the  **question**      you asked.

 That says:   " I do not understand why the existence of the limit in $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ would  not guarantee that $f$ is differentiable at $x$"

Comment: It's really, truly, only a quibble, but one can argue that you are 'not' answering the question - when one writes $\lim_{h \to 0}$, as the question -cough - currently does *not* do, but should, we are implicitly believing in - as you say - the existence and equality of the left and right limits.  The question's (invisible) $h\to 0$' could be bouncing around either side of $0$ - there is no implied $\pm$. But it is a quibble, as we are arguing, and Imre was asking, about 'why the argument is wrong.'

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an example to illustrate that 'the left limit is not equal to right limit' is not the  intrinsic issue, as had been argued on this page: set
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x,\ x\not = 0, \\ 1,\ x =0.\end{cases}$$

Now, $f'(0)$ does not exists, as $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$. On the other hand,
$$ 1 = \lim_{h\to 0} {f(0+h) - f(0-h) \over 2h}. $$
Of course, the left and right limits  implicit in the (non)-definition of $f'(0)$ don't exist either, but...

The point, in the notation of the accepted answer, is the wanted validity of 
$$\lim_{x\to a}\left(\, u(x) + v(x)\, \right) = \lim_{x\to a} u(x) + \lim_{x\to a}v(x).$$
This equation holds *if* the limits on the right exist. In words, we are saying, "if $u$ is close to something, and $v$ close to something else, then $v+v$ is close to the sum of the two somethings." That is to say, the existence of the limits on the right implies the existence of (and calculates) the limit on the left.

However, as the counter-example of the accepted answer shows, it is possible for the sum to be "close to something" without the summands being close to anything at all.

Just as for the addition of limits above, the same holds for subtraction, multiplication, and division of limits. (Although, for division, one has to be careful about dividing by $0$, of course...)

*Irrelevant Note:* For what it's worth: one could say that "limits commutes with addition" (on condition of the existence of limits) is equivalent to the continuity of $+:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, if one defines 'continuity' for functions with domain in $\mathbb R^2$.